# Does ssh-copy-id overwrite previous keys?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I haven't yet found any definitive answer on this using google.

It seems like the answer is **no**, but I need to know for sure before I go ahead and do it.

#### Does `ssh-copy-id` append the key to `authorized_keys` or does it overwrite the previous keys?

Thanks.

*Addendum:*

So the answer is right there in the **man page**. Go figure.

I guess the question can at least help fellow Google-jockeys like me who get a little too used to googling and finding tutorials (that often explain things in layman's terms for us poor folks who have only used Windows our whole lives).

Comment: You should learn to read the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id). They contain useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it appends.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id

ssh-copy-id is a safe operation.

Answer (score 7):

[`man ssh-copy-id`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-copy-id&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+testing+jessie&format=html&locale=en) says:

```
By default it adds the keys by appending them to the remote
user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (creating the file, and directory, if necessary).
```